# Typescript reports that it cannot open tsconfig, and yet it's right there. How come?

Tags: typescript

Notice how I am getting an odd error on tsconfig? This is without atom. As far as I can tell the file is ok, but I might be missing something. Still the error message isn't too helpful.

(By the way, within Atom it also acts odd. When I am looking at the accompanying file1.ts, then it shows an error that the tsconfig.json file is invalid. But when I look at the tsconfig.json file in a different tab in atom, it says that there are no errors.)

So to remove atom from the equation I ran it without atom and saw the results shown here:

```
modu(master)> tsc
error TS6050: Unable to open file 'tsconfig.json'.
modu(master)> ls -l tsconfig.json
-rw-r--r--  1 pitosalas  staff  267 Jul  9 21:27 tsconfig.json
modu(master)> cat tsconfig.json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "outDir": "built/",
        "sourceMap": false,
        "target": "es5",
    },
    "filesGlob": [
        "./**/*.ts"
    ],
    "files": [
        "./file1.ts"
    ]
}
modu(master)>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found it myself. It's an extra comma after "es5" target.

But what an awful error message: "unable to open file tsconfig.json"

Comment: "it shows an error that the tsconfig.json file is invalid" < atom-typescript error should be  "Failed to JSON.parse the project file" which would have guided you to the right direction